# How to make font-size responsive in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, responsive, font-size, dimensions

How to change the font-size according to the view since flex-box doesn't allow changing its font-size in percent. I tried using dimension but that did not work.

Comment: Fix some spacing.

Answer (score 8):

You could scale your fontSize with this code snippet:

```
SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width; // get current width
SCALE = 375; // constant, 375 is standard width of  iphone 6 / 7 / 8 

const scaleFontSize = (fontSize) => {
    const ratio = fontSize / SCALE; // get ratio based on your standard scale 
    const newSize = Math.round(ratio * SCREEN_WIDTH);
    return newSize; 
}
```

Now you can call `scaleFontSize` with your standard fontSize and it will automatically be scaled.

Comment: can we change the fontsize according to the size of the view

Comment: If you know the width of your view, you can replace the SCREEN_WIDTH with your view width. From Dimensions you can't get the width of a specific view.

Comment: You can use the `measure` function to get the component width, however you must use `ref` which gets attached after the initial `render`. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#measurecallback

Comment: @ellekay did this help you?